# titanium : how to get file located inside /res-long-port-ldpi

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, splash-screen

I'm trying to acces a file located in **/assets/android/images/res-long-port-ldpi** at runtime
without success... I tried many path different, but exists() always return false any ideas how to do it ?

```
var path = "/images/res-long-port-ldpi/default.png";
var splashScreenOld = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, path);
Ti.API.info("screen: file exist = "+splashScreenOld.exists());
```

Answer (score 0):

Android natively switches between the density folders based on device density.  This file will be accessible at /images on a low density device.  It is not directly accessible on other density devices.

If you are having trouble switching the splash screens make sure you have deleted the build folder and the app from the test device before re-running.

If you have a different use case please explain a little bit further.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the path set at :/images but no success for opening the file.

My goal is to have random splash screen images when the app is started. It seems that only 1 image named default.png located in one of the directory 
-res-long-port-ldpi 
-res-long-port-hdpi
- etc....

will be loaded and used as splash screen. It seems that appcelerator does not provide a way to have different splash screen. So if i have 4 images in the directory lets say

default.png, default1.png, default3.png, default2.png

i want to open file and rename it at runtime to default.png making the trick of changing the file for having a different splashscreen every time the app is launched.